Duplicidad de datos con pandas
Estoy realizando un merge utilizando pandas en python.
df_xlsx = pd.read_excel(archivo_xlsx, dtype=str)

df_resultado = pd.merge(df_xlsx, frame_sql(), left_on=cuenta_xlsx, right_on='cuenta_10', how='outer',
                        indicator=True)

Como muestra el código utilizo un frame llamado df_xlsx y frame_sql, este último es una función que retorna una frame en de sql.
En df_xlsx tengo cuentas que se duplican, pero en otros datos son diferentes, por ejemplo:
No  NOMBRE DEL COMERCIO TIPO CUENTA CUENTA  CUENTA_10
714220  FARM DEL AHORRO 1   97673113    197673113
16513   MXBA BARRANC    3   97673113    197673113
1596    F A XALAPA  5   97673113    197673113


PROBLEMA:
Al revisar los resultados del merge, se están multiplicando los resultados, es decir, y que esa cuenta esta 3 veces me genera 9 campos con la información. Más especificamente, busca la primera coincidencia de la cuenta con el frame_sql, y lo guarda 3 veces, luego va con la segunda y hace lo mismo, y así sucesivamente. Esto lo realizo con una gran cantidad de cuentas y lo que hago es buscar la coincidencia de cuentas de la base con archivos xlsx.
Espero haberme explicado.
